# $\exp(A)=\exp(B)\Rightarrow A,B$ similar

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential, similar-matrices

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. I want to show the following: If $\exp(A)=\exp(B)$ then $A$ and $B$ are similar. Here 
\begin{align}
\exp:\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, A\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}
\end{align}
denotes the matrix exponential map. I already proved the well-known properties:
$\exp(TXT^{-1})=T\exp(X)T^{-1}$, if $T$ is invertible
and 
$\exp(\operatorname{diag}(a_1,...,a_n))=\operatorname{diag}(\exp(a_1),...,\exp(a_n))$. Does someone have an idea from here?

Comment: That is simply not true and doesn't even work when $n=1$

Comment: For those who are confused (like I was) about why it doesn't work when $n = 1$, let $A = [i \pi]$ and $B = [-i \pi]$.